# Rails Console Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, yaml

I've been trying to get my rails stack set up for the longest time, and so far I've been able to get everything running, but I get this error when I try to run the rails console:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 8 column 0 (Psych::SyntaxError)
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:88:in `database_configuration'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1900:in `<top (required)>'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:32:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:180:in `call'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:180:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:180:in `load_console'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:154:in `block in load_console'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:154:in `load_console'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:26:in `start'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I saw various fixes online, but they didn't end up solving the problem.  Just wondering if anyone else has this same issue or knows how to fix it.  Thanks.

```
Database.yml:
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: shovell_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
    username: root
    password: randompassword12
    host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: shovell_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
    username: root
    password: randompassword12
    host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: shovell_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
    username: root
    password: randompassword12
    host: localhost
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/database.yml` file? It looks like it has a syntax error.

Comment: yes..spacing of parameters in  `config/database.yml` file must be the problem..

Comment: can you edit so that your database.yml content is indended by 4 spaces on each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the formatting of your `database.yml` file. The lines under `timeout: 5000` should not be indended, ie:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: shovell_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: root
  password: randompassword12
  host: localhost
```

Comment: I ended up fixing the main error by indenting all of the lines 4 spaces, but I'm getting this now:

Comment: /Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': development database is not
configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Comment: then there's still something wrong with your database.yml file. Can you paste it to http://pastie.org so we can see exactly how it's set up?

Comment: It's still incorrectly formatted. `development:`, `test:` and `production:` should not be indented. The other lines should be indented by two spaces. See http://pastie.org/1627719 for how it should be indented.

Comment: Got it working, thanks a ton. Don't know why I couldn't figure that out. Need some sleep, I guess :P

Comment: No problem. BTW, once someone has helped answer your question, it's customary (and polite) to mark their answer as "Accepted."

Comment: Clicked the check mark, not sure if that's what I'm supposed to do. Let me know if I need to do something else. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

`username`, `password` and `host` are indented too much.  They should be indented the same as the other parameters under each enviroment name.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the spaces from left side of username, password and host to make it align and try.